# Crash when scrolling in UITableView - object being released unexpectedly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

**Note: I have updated the code based off of aroth's suggestions - however it is still crashing. The code in the below post is the updated code.

I am trying to create an iPhone app based off of the table-view XCode template (XCode 4). The table view gets populated with the correct data in the proper order - however when I go to scroll through the table the app crashes (sometimes I can scroll through 5 or 10 more cells, sometimes it freezes right away). The table view is being fed from 'Artist' objects within an NSArray which is an IVAR of another 'iPodLibraryParser' object. I believe the problem is that the 'iPodLibraryParser' object is being released prematurely - but I don't understand why.

I have created an iPodLibraryParser object with the following header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "ArtistClass.h"

@interface iPodLibraryParser : NSObject {

    //Location stuff
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    IBOutlet UITextField *latitudeTextField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *longitudeTextField;
    IBOutlet UILabel *latitudeLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *longitudeLabel;

    //Music Library Stuff
    NSString *currentArtist;
    NSString *currentAlbum;
    NSMutableArray *artistArray;
    NSMutableArray *sortedArtistArray;       
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sortedArtistArray;

-(void)parseiPodLibrary;
-(id) initializeiPodLibraryParser;

@end
```

The relevant code in the .m file of this Class:

```
@implementation iPodLibraryParser

@synthesize sortedArtistArray;

-(id) initializeiPodLibraryParser{

    [super init];

    sortedArtistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];

    return self;

}

    -(void)parseiPodLibrary{

    .....

NSArray *sortingArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:artistTrackCountSorter,nil];
NSArray *tempSortedArray = [artistArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortingArray];
[sortedArtistArray removeAllObjects];
[sortedArtistArray addObjectsFromArray:tempSortedArray];

    }
```

Artist object header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iPodLibraryParser.h"

@interface ArtistClass : NSObject {

    NSString *artistName;
    int numberOfTracks;

    id artistClassViewController;
}

-(id) initializeArtistObjectWithDocument:(id)myDocument withArtist:(NSString*) artist;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *artistName;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int numberOfTracks;

@end
```

Table View Controller (called RootViewController from the template being used)

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iPodLibraryParser.h"
#import "ArtistClass.h"

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {

    iPodLibraryParser *iPodLibrary;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) iPodLibraryParser *iPodLibrary;

@end
```

Relevant code

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"In viewDidAppear");

    iPodLibrary = [[iPodLibraryParser alloc] initializeiPodLibraryParser];
    [iPodLibrary parseiPodLibrary]; 

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    NSLog(@"there are %i artists in the array", [[iPodLibrary sortedArtistArray] count]);
    return [[iPodLibrary sortedArtistArray] count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"in tableView blah");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.

    NSLog(@"getting row: %i",indexPath.row);

    cell.textLabel.text = [[[iPodLibrary sortedArtistArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] artistName];

    return cell;
}
```

The error is at this line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[iPodLibrary sortedArtistArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] artistName];
```

I tried creating an array with Artist objects that I created within the RootViewController - and that works perfectly (can scroll the entire table with no crashes)

Thanks again!

--Edit:

It is interesting to note that I get different errors at different times:

Most of the times it's just EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[iPodLibrary sortedArtistArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] artistName];
```

Sometimes it's:

```
-[UIAutoRotatingWindow isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1baa80
```

And another had to do with an unrecognized RGB Selector (very strange).

Answer (score 0):

You problem is when you do this:

`sortedArtistArray = [artistArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortingArray];`

The `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` method is returning an autoreleased object, so you shouldn't be surprised when it gets released on you without warning.

Moreover, because your `init` does:

`sortedArtistArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];`

...and because you don't release it before you assign to it, your code is leaking NSArray instances.  I would suggest the following revisions:

1. Make `sortedArtistArray` an `NSMutableArray*`, like:

   `NSMutableArray* sortedArtistArray;`
2. Don't overwrite the array reference in `parseiPodLibrary`.  Instead just copy the sorted dataset into the mutable array, like:

   ```
   -(void)parseiPodLibrary{

       //.....

       NSArray* temp = [artistArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortingArray];
       [sortedArtistArray removeAllObjects];
       [sortedArtistArray addObjectsFromArray:temp];

   }
   ```
3. Don't call `[iPodLibrary retain];` in `viewDidAppear`.  You've already called alloc/init on it, so there is no need to retain it again.
4. Ensure that you call `[iPodLibrary release];` in `viewWillDisappear`, and `[sortedArtistArray release];` in `dealloc` so that you don't leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much more likely that your `iPodLibrary` variable is over-released than that it's the array. You should troubleshoot by splitting your code into a few lines and seeing where it fails:

```
NSArray *artistArray = [iPodLibrary sortedArtistArray];
Artist *artist = [artistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *name = [artist artistName];
cell.textLabel.text = name;
```

Is it possible that your implementation of `initializeiPodLibraryParser` returns an autoreleased object? It shouldn't, as that violates the convention. But it would make sense that that would lead to this problem.

When you call this:

```
iPodLibrary = [[iPodLibraryParser alloc] initializeiPodLibraryParser];
```

you're directly assigning the `iPodLibrary` ivar, so its mutator isn't called and it doesn't matter that the property is marked as retain. If you think it's being implicitly retained, it's likely you're over-releasing it somewhere else. I find you'll understand your own memory management if you use this style to assign properties:

```
iPodLibraryParser *parser = [[iPodLibraryParser alloc] initializeiPodLibraryParser]; // retain count should be 1 if not autoreleased
[self setIpodLibrary:parser]; // retain count is now 2
[parser release]; // retain count is now 1, will go to zero when you release it in dealloc or viewDidUnload
```

Finally, I'd move your `iPodLibrary` initialization from `viewDidAppear` to `viewDidLoad:`. That's where you should be initializing your view. And you should be cleaning up anything you initialize there in `viewDidUnload`, which will be called in a low memory situation.

Comment: Turns out the problem was in my ArtistClass - the artist string was being autoreleased without my knowledge. Breaking out the code into multiple lines was a huge help. Thanks to everyone!!!